# SQL Update returning error message

Tags: php, sql, sql-update, syntax-error

Still new to this and i have come to a point where i am stuck as i cannot see what is going wrong.

I have a users page, when i click a user it opens a different page which shows user details. If i enter data in the input boxes and click update it runs update_user_data.php which should taken the new data and update the table. This however is not working.

It is returning "Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE username= 'jRogers'' at line 1"

Code is below. Please can anyone see where i am going wrong?

```
<?php
require '../php/config.php';

$usernameold = $_POST["username"];
$emailold = $_POST["email"];
$passwordold = $_POST["password"];

$sql = "UPDATE users SET username='$usernameold', email='$emailold', password='$passwordold', WHERE username= '" .$usernameold."'";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
}

?>
```

Comment: this is a typo question

Comment: get rid of the last comma

Comment: ...and the question IMHO.

Comment: You have a redundant comma before the `where` clause

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use **[PHP's built-in functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the password_hash() **[compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)**. Make sure you **[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: don't get your friends to upvote this, 2 upvotes, really??

Comment: thanks for the advice everyone. I have got rid of the comma however i now get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) Line 8

Comment: No friends on here to up vote.

Comment: Ill look into prepare statements now. Good advice

Comment: [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to *use near* `'WHERE username= 'jRogers''` at line 1

The trick with MySQL is to check the string point **before** the "*use near*" location identified by the error.

So:

```
 ... password='$passwordold', WHERE username= '" .$usernameold."'";
                           ^^^
```

*Before* `'WHERE username= 'jRogers` is the comma, the issue is that commas are entity deviders and should not be used at the end of the section.

Fix:

Remove the trailing comma before the MySQL Instruction word.

> ## *PLEASE heed the comments relating to the terrible security and bad practises employed in your SQL and Php.*

---

Bonus:

As [**commented by John Conde**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636511/sql-update-returning-error-message/46636601?noredirect=1#comment80222268_46636511), your issue:

> ```
>   "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'"'
> ```

is caused by having an odd / unbalanced number of quotes (of either type). This is probably caused by your failure to escape your PHP variables (a serious security issue as already mentioned in comments). So if any of your PHP variable values contains only one quote of a pair, this will be interpreted literally by MySQL, unless it is escaped.

Recommended fix: Read the link in all the comments; Use Prepared Statements.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: Thanks Martin. That helped me understand. It seems i still have a lot of reading to do.

Comment: Apologies i clicked up twice however i did not down vote initially. I found your answer really helpful

Comment: @jRogers I have updated the answer with details about your follow up issue.  Cheers for accepting this.